# Is the stack overflow platform for sale?

Tags: discussion, so-engine

If I want to have a website that behaves just like SO but is populated by users asking questions about cars (or waffles or ponies), can I buy or license the platform?

What's available with regard to SAS hosted or frameworks that I can run on my own hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StackExchange](http://www.stackexchange.com).

The hosted on my own server is the option you will be looking for.

```
The Stack Overflow Knowledge Exchange Platform
Designed by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky, Stack Overflow has rapidly 
become the best place for programmers to get answers to technical questions. 
Now there's a way to get the same kind of site for your audience.
```

Comment: My employer has blocked that, they say "http://www.stackexchange.com/ is categorized as Spam Email URLs" .. could jeff have been spamming this?

Comment: Highly doubtful. As far as I am aware there has been no advertising for this apart from the mention here and on the podcast.